# Blank space between table and div with label

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this table with RowFilter function and I show a message for no results found, this message is a label inside a hidden div, the problem is that appears thead items and the next line it's supposed to be the div with the label but not, appears a blank space and then the label. I tried to solve this adding padding 0% to my label and then to the div but nothing work.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  RowFilter();
});

function RowFilter() {
    var busqueda = document.getElementById('buscar');
    var noResults = document.getElementById('no-results');
    var table = document.getElementById("Tabla2").tBodies[0];

    buscaTabla = function () {
        texto = busqueda.value.toLowerCase();
        var match = false;
        var r = 0;
        while (row = table.rows[r++]) {
            if (row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) !== -1) {
                row.style.display = null;
                match = true;
            }
            else {
                row.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        if (!match) {
            noResults.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            noResults.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    busqueda.addEventListener('keyup', buscaTabla);
}
```

```css
 #no-results {
            display: none;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." id="buscar" type="text"/>
</div>

<hr />
<table id="Tabla2" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr class="info">
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Name</td>
     <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>  
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mike</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Steven</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Tyler</td>
      <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="no-results" >
  <label style="width:100%; margin-top:0%;" class="control-label label-warning">No results found... </label>
</div>
```

[Pen with code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mENyrw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's table is a `margin-bottom: 20px`. You can over this value (set to 0) or set the margin-top of your label as `-20px`.

Option #1:

```
<table id="Tabla2" class="table table-striped" style="margin-bottom: 0">
```

Option #2:

```
<div id="no-results" style="margin-top: -20px;">
```

In my opinion, due to that fact that bootstrap's layout will affect all your layout, in this case it will be better to change the `margin-top` of the `no-result` div.
Here is a working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbrvQm

Answer (score 1):

```
.table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The table has a 20px bottom margin pushing the no results found down.